# Combining plots results in missing values

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
Show[Plot3D[vals, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]]

laplaceEqInt = Laplacian[g[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
dcondint = 
  DirichletCondition[
   g[x, y] == 
    Piecewise[{{x, y == -1 || y == 1}, {x, x == 1 || x == -1}}, 0], 
   True];
solint = NDSolve[{laplaceEqInt, dcondint}, g, {x, y} \[Element] intmesh];
valsint = g[x, y] /. solint;
Show[Plot3D[valsint, {x, y} \[Element] intmesh, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]]

Show[Plot3D[vals, {x, y} \[Element] mesh], 
 Plot3D[valsint, {x, y} \[Element] intmesh], PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]
```

[image]

[image]
I'm trying to plot the first and second surfaces together to see what they look like combined; however, I do not understand why there are two circles of missing values in the combined plot.

Comment: Please include the definition for `mesh` and `intmesh` and `g[x,y]`. Thanks.

Comment: Welcoem to Mathematica StackExchange! Include `PlotRange` into first `Plot3D` inside `Show`, namely: `Show[Plot3D[..., PlotRange->{-5,5}], Plot3D[...]]]`.

Comment: @Domen this fixed it! thanks. (new to 
Mathematica)